# How to Auto reload AHK script when focus of a window changes without press any key to reload it?

Tags: autohotkey

-Hy, I'm new to Autohotkey

- I use AHK V 1.1.36.02
- Always, I use this method to reload an AHK script :

  ^r::Reload

but I see this method requires me to press hotkey to do reloading every time I make editing to the script.

- Knowing that VS Code Auto saves changes afterDelay, is there a way to do reloading AHK script automatically when focus of the window loses, without press any key to reload it.
- (the window(program) that I edit in it the script is "VS Code")
  example:
- I made changes to the script in the window of VS Code and then I switch to another window (another program) or anywhere (Desktop),
  I want the script to be automatically reloaded once the focus of VS Code's window loses, I would not press any key to reload it.
- I have tried this method, but it didn't work :

  ```
  #If not WinActive("ahk_exe Code.exe")
      Run, "C:\Users\th\AppData\Local\Programs\Microsoft VS Code\Code.exe"
  #If
  ```
- the script contains hotkeys and hot strings
- Anybody can help? I'll appreciate it, thanks advanced, and Sory for my bad English and the repetition, - I hope my question is clear.

Comment: What is your goal? What does the script do? Why does the script have to be reloaded when VSCode autosaves?

Comment: https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?style=7&t=96079

Comment: Can you post the script?

Comment: the script contains hotkeys and hotstrings

Comment: Yeah but is the `If not WinActive` in a loop for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the subject of the post
[Automatically reload AutoHotkey script when modified](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45468335/automatically-reload-autohotkey-script-when-modified).

The accepted
[answer by LogicDaemon](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45488494/165358)
shows how to set the script itself to check if it was modified
and to reload itself when this happens.
Note that the trick here is that a successful reload will
terminate the current execution flow, so it's easy to detect
that the reload failed.

> Somewhere near start of the script, in the [auto-execute
> section](https://autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#auto)
>
> ```
> #SingleInstance force
> FileGetTime ScriptStartModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%
> SetTimer CheckScriptUpdate, 100, 0x7FFFFFFF ; 100 ms, highest priority
> ```
>
> Anywhere in the script (usually somewhere at the bottom):
>
> ```
> CheckScriptUpdate() {
>     global ScriptStartModTime
>     FileGetTime curModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%
>     If (curModTime == ScriptStartModTime)
>         return
>     SetTimer CheckScriptUpdate, Off
>     Loop
>     {
>         reload
>         Sleep 300 ; ms
>         MsgBox 0x2, %A_ScriptName%, Reload failed. ; 0x2 = Abort/Retry/Ignore
>         IfMsgBox Abort
>             ExitApp
>         IfMsgBox Ignore
>             break
>     } ; loops reload on "Retry"
> }
> ```

Comment: Thank you very much, that is exactly what I was looking for, but there is something intermediate in the code related to the box message. I want to ask if it can be disposed of
- I am new to this site, and I can't explain to you more in this comment place so I hope  you'll look at this post(I wrote this for you)https://superuser.com/questions/1781643/how-to-auto-reload-ahk-script-on-save-when-focus-of-a-window-changes-without-pr

Comment: Everything after the `reload` is optional and can be deleted. These are just checks for serious errors that should either cause the script to exit or to continue in the loop every 300 milliseconds. These checks are beneficial.

Comment: Please see this question (https://superuser.com/questions/1781643/how-to-auto-reload-ahk-script-on-save-when-focus-of-a-window-changes-without-pr)

Comment: People don't like that question. Can't you drag the error message to the side?

Comment: which side? I didn't understand you.

Comment: You said you get more than one error message. I suggest you return the missing `IfMsgBox` command, then you should get only one message. If you get more than obe, you may drag one of them to reveal the other.

Comment: That code works well, and I get one MsgBOx if there is errors in the script. Is there a way to remove the MsgBox?

Comment: If you don't want any message if the reload didn't work, delete the code inside the loop after the `Sleep`. Without the `MsgBox` command there will be no message.

Answer (score 0):

A little different approach. Also has Multi-Tap Reload/Exit Keys set options included.

```
/*
Reload Script … …   Ctrl + HOME key rapidly clicked 2 times. 
Exit Script … … … … Ctrl + Escape key rapidly clicked 3 times.
*/
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
SetKeyDelay, 250     ; Sets the TapCount allowed delay time (milliseconds) for script Exit.  (tied to Reload/Exit routine)
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  

/*
Auto-reload script upon changes:
  - If you make any changes to the script file and save it, the script will automatically reload itself and continue running without manual intervention.
*/

; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
; … … … … Place in Auto-Execute … … … … … …  
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
#SingleInstance, Force 
#Persistent 
SetBatchLines -1 
DetectHiddenWindows, On          ; To detect script.
SetTimer, UpdateCheck, 500       ; Checks for script changes every 1/2 second. (Script Updater)
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … 
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  



; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
; … … … … … …  Place Code Here  … … … … … … 
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  



; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
; … … … …  Place near script end  … … … … … …  
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  

UpdateCheck:                 ; Check if the script file has been modified.
    oldModTime := currentModTime
FileGetTime, currentModTime, %A_ScriptFullPath%

; … … … … If the modification timestamp has changed, reload the script.
    if  (oldModTime = currentModTime) Or (oldModTime = "")
        Return
Reload

; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  

RETURN

; … … … …  
; RELOAD
^Home::           ; … … Ctrl + [Home]
if (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 250) 
{
    TapCount := 1
    KeyWait, Esc
} else {
    TapCount++
    if (TapCount = 2)    ; <<<<---- Set TapCount to # of key taps wanted.
    {
    SoundBeep, 2200, 75
        Reload
} else {
        KeyWait, Esc
    }
}
Return

; … … … …  
; EXIT
^Esc::      ; … …  Ctrl + ([Esc] times (# of TapCounts))
if (A_TimeSincePriorHotkey > 250) 
{
    TapCount := 1
    KeyWait, Esc
} else {
    TapCount++
    if (TapCount = 3)    ; <<<<---- Set TapCount to # of key taps wanted.
    {
    SoundBeep, 2200, 75
        Gui, Destroy
        ExitApp
} else {
        KeyWait, Esc
    }
}
Return

; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …  
; … … … … … SCRIPT  END  … … … … … … … … …
; … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … … …
```